# plot a nonlinear function matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm very new to Matlab and have problem plotting this nonlinear 2D function graph using Matlab.

a lot of errors generated after the below is run.

```
fun1 =  20 + 10 + 15;
fun2 =  20 + (x * 0.00125 ) + 15;
fun3 = (x * 0.0025) + 15;

fplot(fun1,[0 8000])
fplot(fun2,[8000 16000])
fplot(fun2,[16000 positive infinity])
```

I appreciate a lot to your efforts and kindness for replying my question
Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

Your first three expressions do not define functions. Please read the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/function_handle.html?searchHighlight=anonymous_function) about the correct syntax.

```
fun1 = @(x)(20 + 10 + 15);
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a file `fun.m` which contains your function definition

```
function y = fun(x)
  if x < 8000
    y = 20 + 10 + 15;
  elseif x < 16000
    y = 20 + (x * 0.00125) + 15;
  else
    y = x * 0.0025 + 15;
  end
end
```

Then you can plot it with

```
fplot(@fun, [0 24000])
```

which results in

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you do some reading in [fplot](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fplot.html) you will find out that 
for fplot(fun,limits)
fun must be

- The name of a function
- A string with variable x that may be passed to eval, such as 'sin(x)', 'diric(x,10)', or '[sin(x),cos(x)]'
- A function handle

so in your case you need to change all of you fun to strings just add ' before and after the expression

as for the last line change it to be

```
fplot(fun2,[16000 inf])
```

although i don't think this would give you any good results